# Delete the notification for a comment you were mentioned in when the comment is deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, deleted-questions

When a comment is deleted, your notification bar does not show it anymore, but if someone tagged you in a comment and question is deleted, notification for the comment is still there.

It just happened me right now:

[image]

[This is the link from the notification area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610559/java-outputstream-to-string?noredirect=1#comment53072205_32610559)

- This appears for some reason?
- Wouldn't it be useful to delete this notification?

Comment: Well, users above 10k can still see the deleted question.

Comment: I know this, but for users under 10k I think is an useless information,

Comment: No. the notification is very useful. That may be the only link to know when someone has zipped off with your answer cos their task is sorted and they don't care about anyone else. Having said that, I thought this was a fairly recent (few months or more) change.

Comment: Related (currently) unanswered [MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266422/280467)

Comment: @BillWoodger I'm not sure you understand my quesion... or I don't understand your comment... why exactly you think a notification with a broken link is *very useful* ???

Comment: User asks question. I provide answer. Users comments "Thanks, that did it!" User deletes question, because their problem is solved. I paste broken link into flag for Moderator attention. Moderator revives question, and gives me an upvote as a shortcut to user not being able to delete the question again :-)

Comment: **1)** in this case, and for a lot of reasons, user is in his right of deleting the question. **2)** that never happened to me, but happened many others not relating, **3)** you really think this *suposed* 10 rep in one remote case will be worthy enough for all other cases??

Comment: *1) in this case, and for a lot of reasons, user is in his right of deleting the question.* I would be very much interested in hearing about a few of that *lot of reasons*. *3) you really think this supposed 10 rep in one remote case will be worthy enough for all other cases?* Do you really think removing the notification in your specific case will be worthy enough for all other cases?

Comment: now to my mind they come: being a school assignement, is a silly question, can cause harm at your work.... sure you can understand my point...

Comment: *Do you really think removing the notification in your specific case will be worthy enough for all other cases?* all other cases?? you just proposed **one specific and very rare case that can easily have a justification** as in my last comment.... can you provide other cases you mean @FrédéricHamidi?

Comment: @Jordi, I did not propose anything, Bill did. I only pointed out out it looks like you want us to implement a new feature *just for you* but dismiss others who say the feature would be a hindrance *to them*. And I'm still waiting for worthy reasons for the questioner to delete their question in the first place (hint: *being a school assignment, a silly question, can cause harm at work* do not count as worthy in my book).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi in your book may be doesn't, but the [SO rules - FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) do. Maybe it's you who have some interest with this. **I don't**, so about *implement a feature just for me*, nope thanks, I'm just an user that is trying to discuss a (IMHO) bug, and if everybody agrees, make a real feature request.

Comment: I don't find getting notifications of comments I can no longer see useful but  I don't know if it's worth the trouble of getting notifications to behave differently for users under 10K. It just doesn't happen to me that often.

Comment: You could ask for a feature request stating which questions have been deleted in the comments. For example `Java Outputstream to String <Deleted>` and maybe change the color to a shade of red. That way when the question is un-deleted the comment will not suddenly be a new comment in your inbox and simply the `<Deleted>` part would be removed. I think that would be a good compromise, or taking it further you could choose an option to filter out comments that have been removed. That being said it might simply be too rare of a case to really matter.

Comment: Questions on SO are not there solely for the use of the person asking the question. They are supposed to stand as a question for anyone with a similar question. It is not up to the OP to decide to take away a question once it has an answer with score of one or more. It is not up to the OP to delete a question which has a good answer (though score of zero).

Answer (score 5):

I get email. Not a lot, but a fair amount.

Sometimes, I get emails about sales from online vendors.

Sometimes, I don't open those emails for several days, by which time the sale has expired, and clicking on the link to the sale in the email brings me to a 404 error.

Now, there are several ways I could react to this:

1. Get upset at the vendor for not extending the sale for me and demand they keep the sale active until I've taken advantage of it.
2. Get upset at my email provider for not removing the "new email" indicator from that email when the sale (and associated link) has obviously expired.
3. Not get upset at all and realize that I missed out on the sale. Perhaps even just wait until the next sale.

Now, I tend toward option #3, rather than #1 or #2, but that's me. Sure, it'd be nice if the email provider removed the email if it knew that the sale expired, but you know, [tempus fugit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempus_fugit) and all that.